# Replace .Page.UniqueID in hugo to resolve deprecation warning

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

I'm using the blogdown theme:
https://github.com/shawnohare/hugo-tufte

I've fixed most of the build warnings I get, but I'm having trouble resolving this one:

```
Page.UniqueID is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use .File.UniqueID
```

I've tracked down the instance of Page.UniqueID to a couple of files which are used to create margin notes via a shortcode.

```
{{ $marginnoteDomIdSuffix := .Ordinal }}<label for="marginnote-{{ .Page.UniqueID}}-{{ $marginnoteDomIdSuffix }}" class="margin-toggle">&#8853;</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="marginnote-{{ .Page.UniqueID}}-{{ $marginnoteDomIdSuffix }}" class="margin-toggle"/>
<span class="marginnote">{{ .Inner }}</span>
```

I've tried a number of replacements of the .File.UniqueID type (.File.UniqueID, .UniqueID, ..File.UniqueId, you get the idea) as suggested in the warning, but have not had much success.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the entire template. It looks that the theme is of some age. They emphasize in the docs that template always receives .Page variable, which implies it not always has been the case :).

Comment: I've added a link to the full theme. It is indeed very old.